# Why does query select (1/2) * 100 return 0 instead of 50 in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to get 50 as the output instead of 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of integer division; `1/2 = 0`, `0 * 100 = 0`.

Use `1/2.0 * 100` instead

Comment: or swap the order of multiplication and division: 1 * 100 / 2

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because SQL Server is using integer arithmetic for the calculation. The integer part of 1/2 is 0, and 0 * 100 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably doing integer division on the 1/2, evaluating it as 0, so then the whole statement is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The same in C#, Java and VB.net at least: integer arithmetic.

Why do you expect SQL be any different in evaluating expressions to other languages?